# How can i programmatically check a radio button after i read the value from localStorage

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, antd, radio-group

I was implementing a Gender Radio Input. I set its value to localStorage when submitted so that when i return back i can be able to see the one i checked. i managed to read from the localStorage its value but i was not able to check the radio button based on the input value i got.

here is the code for the radio button

```
        <div> 
        <Radio.Group name="radiogroup" onChange={(e) => handleRadioButtons(e)} >
            <Radio 
            checked={genderChecked.male}  
            value={1} 
            >Male</Radio>
            <Radio 
            checked={genderChecked.female} 
            value={2}
            >Female</Radio>
        </Radio.Group>
        </div>
```

Comment: you read from localStorage and save it where? maybe if you provide more of your code and/or add a sandbox it will be easier to help you out.

Comment: forget about the localStorage that is not the issue. i want to focus on programmatically clicking the radio button. for this issue purpose lets assume `const [ genderChecked , setgenderChecked ] = useState({ male: true , female : null}) `  since male is true i expect the male radio button to be clicked when the page renders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to specify `value` on `Radio.Group`. I would suggest change your state for a string value as below to handle easier value changes:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [ genderChecked, setgenderChecked ] = useState('male');
  const handleRadioButtons = e => setgenderChecked(e.target.value);

  return (
    <>
    <Radio.Group onChange={handleRadioButtons} value={genderChecked}>
      <Radio value='male'>Male</Radio>
      <Radio value='female'>Female</Radio>
    </Radio.Group>
    </>
  );
};
```

otherwise your `onChange` handling and `value` would be somewhat convoluted.